# SophosAV slows the dictionary pop-up

Tags: dictionary, anti-virus

I've got the virus scanner from [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx) installed on my Mac with on-access-scan enabled.

**The on-access-scan delays the dictionary pop-up for several seconds for every *first* prompt after boot up.**

You can prompt the dictionary pop-up by using either <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or three fingers double-tab.

I can choose to disable on-access-scan for `/Applications/Dictionary.app` in the SophosAV preferences. However, this does not solve the problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm stupid. Of course one has to exclude the location where the actual dictionaries are located.

In the Sophos preferences you need to exclude the following locations from your on-access-scan:

```
 1. /Library/Dictionaries

 2. /Users/your_username/Library/Dictionaries
```